# Having issue getting a stop on break points using PHP Debug 1.11.1 by Felix Becker

Tags: php, xampp, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to set up PHP debugging in VS Code.  I cannot seem to get the listener to respond.  Here are my settings:

php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote.enable=1
xdebug.remote.autostart=1
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.4-5.5-vc11.dll"
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/gator4123/public_html"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/gator4123/public_html/winemakerssoftware.com"
    ServerName wms.localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/gator4123/public_html/dianestevenslaw.com"
    ServerName law.localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/gator4123/public_html"
    ServerName rwd.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "serverSourceRoot": "E:/gator4123/public_html",
            "localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/",
            "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

My physical root location:

```
E:\gator4123\public_html
```

I have tried for both of these URL and get the same response, dead air.  No output after a connection achieve message when I start the debugging.

start up response:  `<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true }`

```
http://localhost    
http://rwd.localhost
```

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, not the most sophisticated answer, but I did get it working.

**First** was to upgrade XAMPP to latest version including PHP 7.1.1
**Next** was reinstall XDEBUG with a library to match the PHP 7.1.1
**Finally** here are my new file settings

php.ini:

`[XDebug]
 zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.4-7.1-vc14.dll
 xdebug.remote_enable = 1
 xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/gator4123/public_html"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/gator4123/public_html/winemakerssoftware.com"
    ServerName wms.localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/gator4123/public_html/dianestevenslaw.com"
    ServerName law.localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/gator4123/public_html"
    ServerName rwd.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Easy Peasy just like the instructions suggest...